# Why does ArgumentParser return a namespace instead of a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, namespaces, argparse

What is it about a namespace that makes it more ideal for this than and dictionary. Is it just because accessing values like `foo.bar` looks nicer than `foo['bar']`? Can't be. I feel like I must be missing something.

Comment: you can use: `vars(parser.parse_args(...))`

Comment: You're asking about a design decision made by the author of the `argparse` module. There's unlikely to be an objective answer available.

Comment: What do you actually gain by it being a dict?

Comment: @chepner I disagree. I suspect that someone with more knowledge of Python than me could make a very educated guess about this (like you did)

Comment: The `optparse.Values` class is similar, a simple class that can be modified with `setattr` (and read with `getattr`).  This approach minimizes assumptions about what can be stored in the object, and under what name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the reason is flexibility. A class that supports attribute assignment is more general than a class that requires `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`.

Note that `argparse.Namespace` is just the default class for the return value of `parse_args`; you can supply your own via the `namespace` keyword argument.

```
p = ArgumentParser()
# add options

class MyNamespace:
    pass

class MyDictNamespace:
    # Provide __getitem__ and __setitem__ wrappers around getattr and setattr
    ...

p1 = p.parse_args()  # Use the default Namespace class
p2 = p.parse_args(namespace=MyNamespace)
p3 = p.parse_args(namespace=MyDictNamespace)
```